# HttpClient.GetAsync never returns on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, asp.net-core

I am working on an Android application, backed up by an ASP.NET Core application hosted on Azure. I am using a shared Library project to test basic stuff on a Console Application project before making the functionalities for the Xamarin.Forms (Android-only) project.
The following piece of code is run **after** logging into the web service, where `Client` is a `HttpClient`:

```
public static async Task<MyClass> GetInformationAsync(string accountId)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync(UriData + "/" + accountId);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(responseContent);
}
```

Under the same computer/network, the code finishes in less than a second on the Console application, however, it never finishes (even waited a minute) in the `Xamarin.Forms.Android` project.
I find this weird since the Android client can successfully login to the web service using `PostAsync`.

There is a difference, however, on how the Android client and the Console client call `GetInformationAsync`.

While the Console client calls it asynchronously:

```
 private static async void TestDataDownload()
 {
      ...
      var data = await WebApiClient.GetInformationAsync(myId);
 }
```

The Android client calls it synchronously

```
 public void MainPage()
 {
      ...
      var data = WebApiClient.GetInformationAsync(myId).Result;
 }
```

Comment: Are you using local host or local IP address?

Comment: @AthulHarikumar the web service is hosted on a free instance of Azure Web Apps

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems like you are experiencing a deadlock of some sort. You might want to include the code where you actually call `GetInformationAsync`, as it is probably where the problem source is.

You can probably fix your issue by:

1. Not calling `GetInformationAsync` in a sync way
2. Postfixing your async calls in `GetInformationAsync` with `ConfigureAwait(false)` to not switch context on every method call.

So your `GetInformationAsync` method would look like:

```
public static async Task<MyClass> GetInformationAsync(string accountId)
{
    var response = await Client.GetAsync(UriData + "/" + accountId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(responseContent);
}
```

Then if you call it somewhere you need it to return back on the same context, I.e. if you need to update UI:

```
var myClass = await GetInformationAsync(accountId);
// update UI here...
```

Otherwise if you *don't* need to return on the same context:

```
var myClass = await GetInformationAsync(accountId).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Calling GetInformationAsync in an async way worked, without the changes to GetInformationAsync itself. Thanks!

Comment: ConfigureAwait(false) Works for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is the best answer I found about this problem. ConfigureAwait(false) worked for me. Thanks @Cheesebaron.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using http instead of https.
Make sure you add the following lines in Android Mainfest for android.
For More information see the following documentaion https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=windows

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Complete Mainfest File is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.maximop2p" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="MaximoP2P.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
                 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: First of all, this is a very old question. Secondly, what makes you think that whether using HTTPS or HTTP makes a difference to the question posted?