# HttpClient behavior in Xamarin Android APK

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, httpclient

I have an Xamarin.Android APK.

When installed in a tablet locally at the company, it works perfectly. I already installed it in about 3 tablets and it is working as expected.

The problem is when I send the APK to be installed in a tablet at my customer (it is located in another state), it seems that the HttpClient is not working as expected.

To test it, I'm showing a `Toast` with the response of the request. It should return the `Role` of the user.

Locally, it returns the `Role` as expected. In the customer, it returns an empty string. No error is thrown locally and in the server as well.

Searching on the web, I found that this could be related with a [deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088542/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-on-xamarin-android). So, I put a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on my `Get` method:

```
public static async Task<string> CheckLoginAsync(string cpf, string password)
{
    try
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiUrls.Base);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Vault.CreateToken(cpf));
        _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Constants.CheckLoginAsyncTimeout);

        var url = $"{ApiUrls.UserLoginApp}/{cpf}/{password}";

        var result = await _client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response);
        }

        return null;
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException tcex)
    {
        throw new TaskCanceledException("TaskCanceled", tcex.InnerException);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new LoginUnsuccessfulException("LoginFailedDB", ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

After that, it started working and the error started in another method. I try to do the same thing using the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` but the response is coming `null`:

```
private async Task<AppBaseData> GetAppBaseDataAsync(string username)
{
    try
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiUrls.Base);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Vault.CreateToken(username));
        _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Constants.LoadBaseDataAsyncTimeout);

        var url = $"{ApiUrls.SupportAppBaseData}/{username}";

        var result = await _client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppBaseData>(response);
        }

        return null;
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        throw new TaskCanceledException("TaskCanceled", ex.InnerException);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new DataNotReadedException("BaseDataDB", ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

I have no idea of what is causing this problem since it works with the **same** APK locally and in the customer is not working. The customer network have already been changed to a wifi tethering and the behavior still continues.

The above methods are inside a `Task.Run()`.

Comment: I think you need some more logging. There is more to a response than the Content. Find out the http status code, headers etc. Also are exceptions eventually logged somewhere? I only see you throwing them up the call stack.

Comment: While you should not use ConfigureAwait(false) specifically to avoid a deadlock, if you are going to do it anyway you need to do it on all async calls including `ReadAsStringAsync`.

Comment: I have no log for this operations. I'll do the logging to see if I find something useful.

Comment: @Crowcoder After do the logging, I'm getting an Unauthorized Exception. The question is: why? The apk is the same as the installed locally (company). But the apk in the customer doesn't work. I think this is a problem with newer versions of VS2017. I don't know if its a problem with the API or with the APK.

Comment: @Crowcoder Just found the problem: the token. For some reason the token is incorrect. I comment the [Authorize] on my API and it worked.

Comment: I want to remove the token from my app And see if it would work.